# Vagrant make a file writable or executable

Tags: permissions, vagrant, virtualbox, file-permissions

I have found that running

```
chmod u+x myfile
```

Does not work when I ssh into my local vagrant machine.  Same thing for +/- for writable, in fact `chmod` has no effect.  How can I modify permissions inside my vagrant instance?

- Running on Windows 10 machine
- VirtualBox version 5.1.10
- Vagrant 1.8.7

Also this is the line in the Vagrantfile:

```
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

`666` = rw-rw-rw- .. I'm suspecting that permissions aren't changeable since it remains that way no matter what I do.

(To clarify, my purpose is to practice with a PHP shell script, but I can't run the script if it's not executable)

Comment: is it files from a shared folder ? has the shared folder any specific properties ?

Comment: I edited the OP, thanks for pointing that out; it has `fmode=666` which of course is `rw-rw-rw-` - it just doesn't appear to be modifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling vagrant to share the folder in full mode for directory (dmode) but to set permissions as 666 on file so you cant make an executable mode after.

If you have no particular reason to set the directory/file mode for your shared folder, jsut remove the mounting options and leave as

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www"
```

Comment: This worked on the next `vagrant up` session, thanks!  I was concerned this might have an adverse affect on my data, but it did not.  Also, the permissions that I had attempted to set previously "magically appeared" - hope this gives someone else insight.

Answer (score -2):

Below permission should be enough for write and execute.

```
chmod 755 filename
```